# Script to restore SQL Server database fails

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to restore a SQL Server database using a PHP script and it keeps failing. I'm on PHP 7.0.4 NTS x86. Since my code was running inside a framework, I decided to isolate and ran code that I found here (which has also been pointed out in another answer on StackOverflow): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/07/01/restoring-a-sql-server-database-from-php/

The code is as follows:

```
// Set error mode to make sure errors throw exceptions
sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors', 1);

// Try to connect
$conn = sqlsrv_connect(
    'localhost',
    ['Database'=>'master', 'UID'=>'sa', 'PWD'=>'mypassword', 'ReturnDatesAsStrings'=>true, 'CharacterSet'=>'UTF-8']
);

$sql = "RESTORE DATABASE MYDB FROM DISK='c:\\MYDB.bak' WITH RECOVERY";
echo $sql."<br>"; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql); 
if($stmt === false) 
{ 
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors())); 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "Database restored</br>"; 
}

//Put DB into usable state. 
$sql = "USE MYDB"; 
echo $sql."<br>"; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql); 
if($stmt === false) 
{ 
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors())); 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "Using MYDB</br>"; 
}
```

This is the output, the first $stmt === false is true and it prints the error:

```
RESTORE DATABASE MYDB FROM DISK='c:\MYDB.bak' WITH RECOVERY
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01000
            [SQLSTATE] => 01000
            [1] => 4035
            [code] => 4035
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Processed 5496 pages for database 'MYDB', file 'DB_Data' on file 1.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Processed 5496 pages for database 'MYDB', file 'DB_Data' on file 1.
        )

)
1
```

The DB gets created but just appears in Restoring mode. If I try to run the same command from SSMS using the same user, it works fine. Another interesting thing is if I look at the SQL Server log, I see this after every attempt:

```
2017-03-10 09:33:12.37 spid57      The database 'MYDB' is marked RESTORING and is in a state that does not allow recovery to be run.
2017-03-10 09:33:34.76 spid57      Starting up database 'AdventureWorks2008R2'.
2017-03-10 09:33:34.80 spid57      Starting up database 'ReportServer'.
2017-03-10 09:33:34.83 spid57      Starting up database 'ReportServerTempDB'.
```

Not sure why it's starting up those same 3 databases every time after the restore is attempted.

I also tried doing the restore using PDO, same result, a database stuck in Restoring mode.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but wonder if the `USE MYDB` query is being executed before the restore is complete.  Can you do something hacky like throw a `sleep()` between your queries to see if that might work?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter It never even makes it to that part of the code because of the die(). But since stranger things have happened, I tried it anyway, and it confirmed it, the script never even sleeps because it never makes it that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server prints warnings and errors pretty much the same way-- just with a different severity level so the client software can know the difference and take appropriate action.

I don't know PHP, so I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the line

```
sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors', 1);
```

But from the sounds of it, that is making the lower severity "warning" messages from SQL Server get treated as actual errors by your client code.  Set that to 0 and I'm guessing your script will continue past the restore database messages and treat them as informational rather than exceptions.

Comment: I came to this realization shortly after posting this. Noticed that it didn't make sense the same text that gets outputted on success in SSMS was being outputted as an error, figured it was likely a warning being converted to an error and halting the process. Looks like you figured it out a lot faster than I did though, thanks for the answer, you got yourself a winner!